# Why does a module with a submodule and a function with conflicting names work?

Tags: rust

Here's the code I'm wondering about: ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=mod%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20mod%20b%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20b()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22b%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20use%20self%3A%3Ab%3A%3Ab%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ause%20a%3A%3Ab%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20b()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%3Ab()%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0))

```
mod a {
    pub mod b {
        pub fn b() {
            println!("b");
        }
    }

    pub use self::b::b;
}

use a::b;

fn main() {
    b();
    b::b();
}
```

Why does `b::b()` work? Shouldn't the module `b` and the function `b` conflict? Does that mean that `a::b` is both a module and a function somehow?

Comment: [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=mod%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20mod%20b%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pub%20use%20super%3A%3Ab%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20b()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22b%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ause%20a%3A%3Ab%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20b()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%3Ab()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%3Ab%3A%3Ab()%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0) works too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't the module `b` and the function `b` conflict?

No, because they're in different namespaces.  They conflict in the same way "re*c*ord" and "*re*cord" conflict in English: they're spelled and sound the same, but mean different things, and you can tell which is which based on context.

You can't call a module, so `b()` can't be talking about a module.  Functions don't have child items, so `b::b` can't be talking about a function.  This is important when you consider things like `struct S(i32);`.  `S` is *both* a type (the structure type itself) *and* a function (the constructor).