# How can a Rust module have the same name as a const in the same namespace?

Tags: rust

I came across some code in a piece of published code that had something like the following structure (which compiles and runs fine):

```rust
pub mod foo {
    pub const BAR: u32 = 53;

    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    pub mod BAR {
        pub fn eep() {
            println!("This is attached to BAR");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!, {}", foo::BAR);
    foo::BAR::eep();
}
```

This seems strange and interesting to me. The strange bit being `BAR` being defined as both a `const` and a `mod`.

Is this idiomatic Rust?

What is going on here? Should I be able to find out about this in the docs? When is such a pattern valid?

I can see that this might be useful, but is there some really compelling use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not idiomatic, and the compiler already tells you this:

```
warning: module `BAR` should have a snake case name
 --> src/main.rs:4:13
  |
4 |     pub mod BAR {
  |             ^^^ help: convert the identifier to snake case: `bar`
  |
  = note: #[warn(non_snake_case)] on by default
```

The warning has been silenced in the code you have presented, for whatever reason.

> normally whilst programming one can't attach the same label to multiple constructs in the same namespace

That's correct. Modules and constants are in [different namespaces](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustc-guide/name-resolution.html#namespaces). There are three namespaces:

- types
- values
- macros

```
fn main() {
    macro_rules! BAR { () => {} }
    mod BAR {}
    let BAR = 1;
}
```

Modules are in the type namespace.

> I don't understand what `BAR` is. Is it a module, or is it a const?

There's one of each.

See also:

- [Why does a module with a submodule and a function with conflicting names work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43358940/155423)

---

I'd probably write this:

```
pub mod foo {
    use std::fmt;

    pub const BAR: Bar = Bar(53);

    pub struct Bar(u32);

    impl Bar {
        pub fn eep(&self) {
            println!("This is attached to Bar");
        }
    }

    impl fmt::Display for Bar {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
            self.0.fmt(f)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!, {}", foo::BAR);
    foo::BAR.eep();
}
```

Comment: Ok, that answers the idiomatic bit. I'm still curious what is going on though. Are you able to provide some insights into that? The complaint seems to be around good coding standards rather than strictly being erroneous.

Comment: @HenryGomersall what do you mean? As you already pointed out: *which compiles and runs fine*. There's nothing **technically** wrong about the code. That's why it's a warning and not an error.

Comment: @HenryGomersall *What is going on here?* — someone created a module with the same name as a const (but you know that). *Should I be able to find out about this in the docs?* Find out about what, creating modules / creating constants / idiomatic naming? *When is such a pattern valid?* — what "pattern"? what do you mean by "valid"? *I can see that this might be useful, but is there some really compelling use case?* — presumably whatever case where you see it being useful...

Comment: well, normally whilst programming one can't attach the same label to multiple constructs in the same namespace, and I understand Rust to be against overloading in principle, so I don't understand what `BAR` is. Is it a module, or is it a `const`?

Comment: There's no overloading going on, constants and type names exist in different namespaces therefore they refer to distinct things.

Comment: @WesleyWiser you might want to @-mention, otherwise I think I'm the only one who gets notified.

Comment: The [answer in your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43359214/709852) gives the important insight as to why this way of thinking is necessary - specifically that types are generally callable in order to instantiate them. The Rust model for this is that the different ways of interacting with the label are present in different namespaces.